# Testing fat models / skinny controllers

Tags: laravel, testing

Laravel's creator (Taylor Otwell) has been publicly vouching for the "fat models / skinny controllers" coding style for quite some time now.

I've been pondering about the testing part of it. Imagine the following model with rich public API (fat model):

```
class User extends Model
{
    ...

    public function updateProfilePhoto(...)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

And the following controller:

```
class UserController extends Controller 
{
    ...
    
    public function update(Request $request, User $user)
    {
         ...

         $user->updateProfilePhoto(...);

         ...
    }
}
```

When writing tests, I'd first write a test for the `updateProfilePhoto` method on the `User` model to make sure it works as expected. And then write a HTTP test for the controller.
But what should that test look like? Ideally we could check if the `updateProfilePhoto` method has been called because that's already covered. But models aren't easily mockable. So that makes me wonder if the entire profile photo update should be tested in the HTTP test as well (and hence duplicate the method's test)?

How do you deal with testing your fat models and the controllers they're used in?

Answer (score 0):

So, what I would do (and I have been doing for at least 3 years) is create a `Domain` folder (`\App\Domain`) and put everything in there. Instead of having `\App\Models\User->updateProfilePhoto` have `\App\Domain\User\Actions->updateProfilePhoto` or similar, so the business logic is inside the `\App\Domain\User\Actions` class and the model remains skinny too, no need to have a 5k lines of code model.

Then, the question would be: do I mock this `Actions` class and just assert on my test that the controller is calling it or do I only test the controller?

I do only test the controller, if I have to use this action in another place, let's say a console command, then I create a new feature test for that command and I just write it as I had no idea `updateProfilePhoto` exists.

If you do mock `Actions` then you are coupling your test a lot with an implementation. In the future, if it changes (only the implementation, not the I/O) then the test should still pass, but if you are mocking the `Actions` class, your test will definitely have to be updated for them to pass, that is not the idea of TDD at all (or any feature test honestly).

You do not need to unit test that action if you are correctly feature testing the whole. You may argue: what if I need a 3rd parameter on that method and it does something extra, but, for now, no one is using it? Then I would either create a fake route when you run a test and simulate that outcome, or only in that case unit test that specific case directly from the `Actions` class, else a normal feature test should be covering that behaviour.

Check my user profile as I do have some broad answers related to testing, maybe one will help you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm aware of that coding style and have been using it as well. But it circumvents the actual question in the OP: how to properly test in case the fat model approach is used. I've been thinking about it for too long so I figured I'd ask it.

Comment: Well, I do not think I am circumventing the question, I am giving you another solution. Still, in your case, I would not mock anything, as you said, you have to mock a lot of things in a model, and it could be harmful (maybe you mock a method where a scope should be applied, but because you are not mocking that too, the scope is not applied, so you are not changing how it behaves). If you still want to do something, maybe you can `spy` instead of `mock` and make sure that the method from that model was called